# MySQL DATE_ADD running too slow with dynamic interval

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, dateadd

I have the following query that's running pretty slow when executing it on thousands of records.

```
SELECT
    name,
    id
FROM
   meetings
WHERE
  meeting_date < '2014-09-20 11:00:00' AND (
  meeting_date >= '2014-09-20 09:00:00' OR
  DATE_ADD(meeting_date, INTERVAL meeting_length SECOND) > '2014-09-20 09:00:00'
)
```

The query checks if `meeting_date` overlaps in anyway between `2014-09-20 09:00:00` and `2014-09-20 11:00:00`. The above query covers all the possible overlapping cases. However, `DATE_ADD` adds a lot of overhead.

Anyway to optimize `DATE_ADD`? Removing DATE_ADD greatly boosts the performance but it won't cover all overlapping cases.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the value of `meeting_length`?

Comment: It don't think it's really the `DATE_ADD` function per se; rather, it's the number of rows that the expression has to be evaluated for, because of the `OR`, and because the predicate on the expression isn't sargable.

Comment: @OllieJones, not really an upper bound on the meeting length, but it's safe to assume no more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you eliminate the `OR`.

MySQL won't (can't) perform a range scan operation on an index on column `meeting_date` when that column is wrapped in a function.

When the comparison is against the bare column, MySQL can do a range scan. But with the comparison to an expression, MySQL has to evaluate that expression for *every* row in the table, and then comapare.

For a large table, we'd get optimal performance with an index with leading column of `meeting_date`.

I think the "trick" to getting better performance is to rewrite the query to introduce some additional domain knowledge. Specifically, what are the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM values for `meeting_length`?

I think it's pretty safe to assume it won't be negative. And we probably don't expect it to be zero. But even if the minimum length is greater than zero, we can use zero as our "known" minimum. (It's going to turn out to be more convenient than some other non-zero value.)

What we really need to know is the MAXIMUM value for `meeting_length`.  If that's a known constant value, that would be great, because we're going to include that value in the query. let's assume the maximum value of `meeting_length` is the number of seconds in 7 days.

As a demonstration of what I'm thinking:

```
SELECT m.name
     , m.id
  FROM meetings m
 WHERE m.meeting_date  < '2014-09-20 11:00:00' 
   AND m.meeting_date  > '2014-09-20 09:00:00' + INTERVAL -7 DAY
HAVING m.meeting_date  + INTERVAL meeting_length SECOND 
                       > '2014-09-20 09:00:00'
```

Let's unwrap that a bit.

The first predicate is the same as in your original query... the "start" time of the meeting is *before* the "end" of the specified period.

The third predicate is the same as in your query too... the "end" of the meeting is *after* the beginning of the specified period. (My personal preference is to use the `+ INTERVAL` form to add a duration to datetime.)

So, just like the original query we're looking for overlap.

I'm suggesting that we include another sargable predicate. The addition of this predicate doesn't really change the check for the overlap, given that we have a known minimum of 0 for meeting_length. What it does do is add a fixed lower bound that we can check against.

To explain that a little bit... if a meeting row that satisfies the condition "meeting end is after the period start", then we also know, for that row, that "meeting start is after (period start MINUS meeting length)". And we also know that "meeting start is after (period start MINUS the MAXIMUM possible value of meeting length.

And for most rows, that's  going to be a bigger range... but the "trick" is the the predicate that checks that can compare a "bare" column against a constant.

And that means MySQL will be able to use an index range scan operation to satisfy that. The query is of the form:

```
 WHERE meeting_date > const 
   AND meeting_date < const
```

And that's perfect for an index range scan. That should benefit performance... assuming there's a suitable index and that significantly limits the number of rows that need to be checked.

But by itself, that returns more rows than we need, we're going to get some meetings that start and end before the start of the period.

So we still need the additional check, to further filter down the rows. But that won't have to be evaluated for every row, only the rows that are pass through the first two predicates.

```
   AND meeting_date + length > const
```

We just need to MySQL to recognize that it `length` won't ever be negative; to recognize that this is actually a "stricter" range, not a broader range. It might work with the `AND`, but we can force MySQL to evaluate that condition later, by including it in the `HAVING` clause.

```
HAVING meeting_date + length > const
```

But, all of that is really just a guess.

We'd really need to take a look at the EXPLAIN output.

If that index with the leading column of meeting_date also includes the id and name columns, then MySQL could satisfy the query entirely from the index, without any need to reference pages in the underlying table. (If that happens, we'll see "Using index" in the EXPLAIN output.)

---

Earlier, I said it would be convenient if we had a known constant for maximum `meeting_length`.

We could also use a query to determine that from the data:

```
SELECT MAX(meeting_length) FROM meetings
```

(And index with meeting_length as the leading column will avoid having to do an expensive full scan of the table)

We use that value to derive the "constant" value in the predicate.

We could include that query (as an inline view or a subquery), but that might impact performance. (We'd need to test how "smart" MySQL optimizer is...

We could try it as a subquery:

```
SELECT m.name
     , m.id
  FROM meetings m
 WHERE m.meeting_date  < '2014-09-20 11:00:00' 
   AND m.meeting_date  > '2014-09-20 09:00:00' 
                       - INTERVAL (SELECT MAX(l.meeting_length) FROM meetings l) DAY
HAVING m.meeting_date  + INTERVAL meeting_length SECOND 
                       > '2014-09-20 09:00:00'
```

Or try it as an inline view:

```
SELECT m.name
     , m.id
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(l.meeting_length) AS max_seconds
           FROM meetings l
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN meetings m
 WHERE m.meeting_date  < '2014-09-20 11:00:00' 
   AND m.meeting_date  > '2014-09-20 09:00:00' 
                       - INTERVAL d.max_seconds SECOND
HAVING m.meeting_date  + INTERVAL meeting_length SECOND 
                       > '2014-09-20 09:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Indeed it does the trick. I used the subquery to grab the max meeting_length.

Comment: @PeteDarrow: That subquery should get evaluated just one time, and then the right side of the comparison will essentially be a constant. The EXPLAIN output should show a "range" operation on the index; I'm not sure if that will show "const", but at least it shouldn't show DEPENDENT SUBQUERY. As long as someone doesn't add a row with a HUGE meeting_length value, that should limit the number of rows to be checked.

Comment: @PeteDarrow: Did you experiment with replacing `HAVING` keyword with `AND`, to test performance when that third predicate is moved to the WHERE clause? (That could either go horribly, back to performance the way it was before. Or, it could improve performance a bit.) Predicates in the WHERE clause are evaluated as rows are accessed. limiting rows retrieved. Predicates in the HAVING clause get evaluated much later, after all the rows have been retrieved.)

Comment: I removed the `HAVING` clause and performance appear to be the same or perhaps a bit better than using `HAVING`. Thanks for the tip.